# issue with sort data

Tags: java, android

i am developing an app in which i get data from server and display in map. but before display it on map's balloon i have just sort data by one field name is "Destination" and there are method made na,e is ..GOTOSORT....

now problem is i got variables `s` with length 1 and there for the for loop are run only 1 time , but there are 42 data are come from webservices so please check it and tell me what is the problem

```
private void GOTOSORT() {

        Log.i(TAG, " SORT ");
        Map<Float, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Float, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < lng_timeStamp.length; ++i) {
            map.put((float) lng_timeStamp[i], i);
        }
        Collection<Integer> indices = map.values();
        System.out.println("indices" + indices);
        Integer s[] = (Integer[]) indices.toArray(new Integer[0]);

        Log.i(TAG, "s.length"+s.length);
        for (int i = 0, n = s.length; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(s[i]);

            int_sort_MyhourGetTime[i] = int_MyhourGetTime[s[i]];
            int_sort_MyMinGetTime[i] = int_MyMinGetTime[s[i]];
            lng_sor_timeStamp[i] = lng_timeStamp[s[i]];
            arr_sort_ServiceNumber[i] = arr_ServiceNumber[s[i]];
            arr_sort_Destination[i] = arr_Destination[s[i]];

        }
```

Comment: Use `indices.size();` in foe loop

Comment: its not getting me any effect

Comment: here i have print indices size and it getting me 1

Comment: here case it i have take `lng_timeStamp` for sorting and all data of that are 302, suppose from 0 index to last index it getting me same and it come from webservices. now problem is.....

Comment: it is overwrite as per my think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort your list , you should follow the Java's comparator[Follow here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/comparator-and-comparable-in-java.html)
It will return you a sorted list in any order.

All the best !! :)